# Make paper snowflakes!

Tags: code-golf, ascii-art

## The task

Given a folded and cut in places snowflake, "unwrap" it and output the result

## Input

The base folded snowflake, without any cuts, looks like:

```
|\
| \
|  \
|   \
|    \
|     \
|      \
|       \
|________\
```

And the input will always resemble this.
No changed or added symbols will go out of the range of this triangle, so

```
 |\
 | \
-|  \
 |   \  o 0
 |    \
 |     \ 
 |      \.
 |       \
 |________\
```

is not a valid input.

### Possible changes and additions:

1. Corner cuts

```
minimal cut:
 _
| \
|  \
|   \
|    \
|     \
|      \
|_      \
  |_____/
```

```
Big, different cuts with cuts in them:


|\_/\
|    \
|     \
|___   \
   _|  _|
  |___/
```

2. Side cuts

```
minimal cuts, in random places on the sides:

|\
| \
|  \
|  |_
|    \
 \    \
 /     \
|       \
|____/\__\
```

```
Big, recursive cuts:
|\
| \
 \ \
  \|
  /|
 | |  _
 / |_| \
| |\___ \
|_|    \_\
```

And, of course, both types can be present at the same time.

## Output

An "unfolded" snowflake. Here is an explanation of the unfold:

```
Say we have a snowflake
 __
|  \
|   \
|    \
 \    \
 /     \
|       /
|______/

Which we will, for the explanation, remake as:

 aa
1  1
2   2
3    3
 b    4
 b     5
1       c
2123456c

Where each uncut piece of sides is numbered from 1 to 9, and each cut has its own letter.
On the first unfold, you will get
    123  12
   a   bb 1
 aaa      2
1         3
2         4
3         5
 b        c
 b       c
1       c
2123456c

Which looks like
    ___  __
   |   \/ |
 __|      |
|         |
|         |
|         |
 \       /
 /      /
|      /
|_____/



Then, on the next unfold, we get:
    123  1221  321
   a   bb    bb   a
 aaa              aaa
1                    1
2                    2
3                    3
 b        cc        b
 b       c  c       b
1       c    c       1
2123456c      c6543212

Which looks like

    ___  ____  ___
   |   \/    \/   |
 __|              |__
|                    |
|                    |
|                    |
 \        /\        /
 /       /  \       \
|       /    \       |
|______/      \______|

If you would want another unfold, the scheme looks fine:

    123  1221  321
   a   bb    bb   a
 aaa              aaa
1                    1
2                    2
3                    3
 b        cc        b
 b       c  c       b
1       c    c       1
2      c      c      2
2      c      c      2
1       c    c       1
 b       c  c       b
 b        cc        b
3                    3
2                    2
1                    1
 aaa              aaa
   a   bb    bb   a
    123  1221  321

Until you actually make it in ascii:

    ___  ____  ___
   |   \/    \/   |
 __|              |__
|                    |
|                    |
|                    |
 \        /\        /
 /       /  \       \
|       /    \       |
|      /      \      |
|      \      /      |
|       \    /       |
 \       \  /       /
 /        \/        \
|                    |
|                    |
|                    |
 __|              |__
   |   /\    /\   |
    ___  ____  ___

So, for this challenge, I have chosen not to go for another unfold.
```

Here is another example on one of the snowflakes, without the scheme:

```
|\
| \
|  \
|   \
 \   \
 /    \
|      \
|  /\   \
|_/  \__/

Then, on the first unfold turns to:
____  ____
|   \/    |
|         /
|        /
|        \
 \        \
 /        |
|         |
|  /\    /
|_/  \__/

And then:
 ____  ________  ____
|    \/        \/    |
|         /\         |
|        /  \        |
|        \  /        |
 \        \/        /
 /                  \
|                    |
|  /\            /\  |
|_/  \__________/  \_|
```

Notice how, on the first unfold, the bottom side of the triangle translates to the right side of the square and, the same, with the left and top side.

## Output

The final result, so

```
 ____  ________  ____
|    \/        \/    |
|         /\         |
|        /  \        |
|        \  /        |
 \        \/        /
 /                  \
|                    |
|  /\            /\  |
|_/  \__________/  \_|
```

for the example.

This is code-golf, so lowest byte-count wins!

Comment: I still don't understand the first unfolding. In your first example (right below the "Output" heading), the bottom edge has `123456`, but the unfolded right edge has only `12345`. Where does the `6` go?

Comment: Why do in the second example the bottom three left-hand side `|` become four top-right `_` after the first unfold?

Comment: Also in the second example (second unfold): where did the bottom gap go? Shouldn't the result be [this](https://pastebin.com/3bKNLy3G) instead? Although in that case I'm also wondering why the two `_` at the bottom have become three `_` from the first to second unfold.